# Why does my toilet pause and bubble when flushed?

Tags: toilet

The water in my toilet goes down pretty fast, but in an abnormal kind of way. It's hard to describe it in words. Instead of immediately rushing down the water waits a second and then goes down and empties the bowl completely. But at the end it makes the bubblying sounds and when everything stops there is no water in the bowl. I poured liquid plumber and plunged it repeatedly, but to no avail. 
It is more or less functional, but I'm afraid this is a symptom of a bigger problem  and if I don't take care of it now, there is a disaster lurking down there.

Thanks,

Comment: Does it empty your tank & the bowl? Take the cover off the back and flush it and watch. The flapper should seat as the water empties and the tank begin filling. The bowl should fill with the water from the tank. This, or possibly a vent is clogged. How does a full tub of water fare when drained? Is it normal?

Answer (score 3):

Probably a clogged vent. Take a garden hose up on the roof and run it into the vent pipe. The water should drain immediately. If it overflows the vent pipe you have a clog. Yu can try to clear it by sending a plumbing rod down the vent pipe. Could be leaves, sticks and stuff